# Optical Character Recognition in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, ocr

I am working on core application in blackberry in which I need to perform OCR task.

Till now I have searched and found out that there are few online API's like ABBY which allows to read image and returns text file, but they are not free, after a few trails they charge a amount.

Can I perform Optical character recognition on device end completely with server implementation.
Please suggest me for this task.

**EDITED:** I am working with the following code

```
public String serverUrl = "http://cloud.ocrsdk.com";
    static final String BOUNDARY = "----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy";


    public byte[] send() throws Exception
    {
        HttpConnection hc = null;

        InputStream is = null;

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte[] res = null;

        try
        {
            hc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(serverUrl+"/processImage/"+"language=en&exportFormat=txt");

            hc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/image-JPG; boundary=" + BOUNDARY);
            /*hc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(SERVICE_URL);
            hc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + BOUNDARY);
            hc.setRequestProperty(PARAM_IMAGE, "");
            hc.setRequestProperty(PARAM_LANGUAGE, lang);
            hc.setRequestProperty(PARAM_APIKEY, key);*/

            hc.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);

            OutputStream dout = hc.openOutputStream();

            dout.write(raw);

            dout.close();

            int ch;
            StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer();
            is = hc.openInputStream();

            while ((ch = is.read()) != -1)
            {
                bos.write(ch);
                sb.append(ch);
            }
            System.out.println(sb);
            res = bos.toByteArray();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if(bos != null)
                    bos.close();

                if(is != null)
                    is.close();

                if(hc != null)
                    hc.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e2)
            {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

But even with this code its not working. I am getting 200 as response code after making HTTP request.
but not getting perfect response as expected the text. In response I am getting ERROR PAGE of ABBYY.  http://cloud.ocrsdk.com/GenericError.htm?aspxerrorpath=/processImage/language=English&exportFormat=txt;connectionhandler=httpc

Please suggest me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am done with the task OCR.

The code which I get from GitHub for Java is incomplete or may be not working from my side.
I have perform the implementation of OCR functionality on my PHP server.
And its working successfully.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you want to implement your own OCR application for BlackBerry device, and you want to send image to server, recognize it and send text file back to the device.

There's an open source OCR implementation, check this link: http://en.openocr.org/

Use this information to implement OCR server functionality. BlackBerry client functionality will be trivial. Just use `HTTPConnection` class and stream classes to upload/download files to and from the server.

**EDIT**:

Noticed that there's no direct source code download available from openocr.org. They need an email request to be sent to cuneiform@cognitive.ru, and they will consider it. I think it is not a convenient way.

Let's check another sources, for instance [Tesseract OCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/). By the link you can download source codes and build OCR application. Then implement server-wrapper for this application which works via HTTP, and write blackberry client that uploads image file via HTTP to this server, and gets result text file.

Comment: hello Rafael, thanks for such great guidance. 
I have one more query, do we create our own server to implement this OCR functionality?
Or we have use this openOCR to send request in image form or base64 bytes and wait for response in .txt form of document.
Please suggest me.

Comment: OpenOCR is not a server application, it is a standalone application without client-server interaction functionality. From my point of view you will need to build OpenOCR application, implement server functionality, that gets requests from clients and works with OpenOCR (runs Runtime.exec() in java, etc) and sends recognized text files to mobile clients.

Comment: Rafael, I was just now trying to getting some information from the link provided by you. It asked to create my account. But I didn't get confirmation yet.
Also, I am a bit confused now. What I need to do, as a Blackberry developer to implement this functionality?:(
Is it a pay account after a few hits??

Comment: Tesseract OCR didn't provide any Java code. I tried to work with ABBY by getting exception, Don't know where to use my App ID and paasword while making request.
Also tried with http://ocrapiservice.com OCR online by again getting exception and the code is not working. 
The problem is, that I am still in search of a trustful API which I can use for my app.
Please suggest me.

Comment: I think it should be possible to compile Tesseract OCR Engine and use [JNI (java native interface)](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html) on your server java application to invoke necessary Tesseract functionality.